# How do i replace all elements of an array that satisfy a condition?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have the cell array:

```
im = {'A+','B-','B+','A+'; 'A-','B-', NaN, 'A+'};
```

I want to loop through each row to see which ones that have both sums of 'A's and 'B's equal to 2. Then i would replace these rows with NaNs. I have the code:

```
for ii = 1: size(im,1)
  if (sum(strcmp('A+', im), 2) + sum(strcmp('A-', im), 2)) == 2 & (sum(strcmp('B+', im), 2) + sum(strcmp('B-', im), 2))== 2

     im{ii, 1} = NaN;
     im{ii, 2} = NaN;
     im{ii, 3} = NaN;
     im{ii, 4} = NaN;       
  end
end
```

When i remove the 2nd row from `im`, i get the ans: `im = {NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN}`. However, when i include the 2nd row, `im` remains as it is originally. Please, what could possibly be wrong with my code? Secondly, is there a better way to replace the elements?

Any help or suggestions please??? Many thanks.

Comment: Since you don't tell Matlab what to do in case the sum is not 2 for both A's and B's it leaves it unchanged, as you are observing. You could add an `elseif` statement inside your loop to take care of that case

Comment: To fix your code, change the conditions like this: `if sum(strcmp('A+', im(ii,:))) + ....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because in the `if` statement you are checking for the sum in the whole cell, not just in a single row. You should use something like this:

```
if (sum(strcmp('A+', im(ii,:)), 2) + sum(strcmp('A-', im(ii,:)), 2)) == 2 & (sum(strcmp('B+', im(ii,:)), 2) + sum(strcmp('B-', im(ii,:)), 2))== 2
```

Additionaly, you can change your next four lines for a single one like this:

```
im(ii,:) = {NaN}
```